# How "slow" is python for game development?

Tags: python, performance

I'd like to try my hand at some PC game development.  I keep hearing that python is slow compared to C++.  Is this something I should be worried about?

I am more familiar with python than C++.  If I'm looking to make some games, should I take the time to learn C++ or just stick with Python?

Comment: What type of game? Is it something simple like sudoku or a 3d FPS?

Comment: Also, consider that a number of games *use* python (or another "scripting" language, such as LUA) underneath. That is, the heavy graphics/rendering/physics (where CPU/GPU crunching really matters) may be done on an engine written in C/C++ while that game logic/mechanics can be (and often are) handed off.

Answer (score 14):

There's a difference in being slow for development and being slow at runtime. Be careful not to get the two confused.

Many games spend most of their time waiting for user input or waiting for a timer to tick. In these cases the runtime speed is generally of little importance and more important is the development speed - getting your game to market as fast as possible and as cheap as possible, and making the game as good as you can with your given budget. For this type of game high level languages are an appropriate choice.

For games which require high performance generally the engine is written in a language like C++ but the scripting can still be done in a high level language. Python isn't the only choice. [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html) is probably the most popular choice for a scripting language in games.

Comment: although i agree with you, simply reading "Pontifical Catholic University of Rio de Janeiro in Brazil" is making me never to recommend this, but this: stackless python!

Comment: @StefanNch Whatever you're drinking... I want some

Answer (score 6):

Elebenty-seven.

No, really, it's fast enough for most things, and can drop to C when you really need speed. Profile twice, optimize once.

Comment: Spelling error - that's "Elebenty-seven"

Answer (score 4):

The kind of game matters immensely. High performance games like the big name PC or console games are almost exclusively the domain of C++.

Casual games can be written in almost any language, including *slower* languages like Python.

If you're a garage type developer who gets his hands wet with some simple game development for this first time, Python would be more than enough. If you however have the ambition to work for a game developer studio, I would definitely recommend learning C++.

Answer (score 2):

Many if not most top-end commercial games these days include some kind of scripting engine for game logic. Game logic decisions, for the most part, aren't particularly performance-sensitive in the way that e.g. the rendering engine is.

BTW - I'm not claiming any insider knowledge of game development - this is fairly well known outside the industry. Some games publishers have even allowed users access to the scripting stuff and other tools for games modding - for years.

If you find a game engine that is wrapped to be used in Python, you'll be dealing with the same basic principles. Write the game logic in Python, and you'll probably be fine.

PyGame is basically SDL wrapped for Python, supporting basic 2D games for the most part (though OpenGL can be used for 3D in SDL - not sure for PyGame).

It's a good starting point. You may hit a performance issue with managing your game objects and running your blit loop, since only very basic graphics stuff is handled by SDL, but you should find that it's just fine for most things.

As Ignacio implies - worry about performance problems when you know you have performance problems, not before. Some performance problems are predictable in advance, but if you're not writing the actual game engine in Python, you should be OK - don't fall into the premature optimisation trap, IOW.

Answer (score -3):

C++ is much more easier for object orientation.  When you're doing things, it's easier to keep track of everything, because most IDEs for C++ are more based on projects, were as IDLE is more based on single files.

The bottom line is for game development, use what you're comfortable with using.  I mean, game development is about what you want to do, not what would be better, because better == what you want.